# Typescript Assigning dynamic variable to Map object

Tags: typescript

I'm working on this problem (from [Exercism](https://exercism.io))

Given a phrase, count the occurrences of each word in that phrase.

For example for the input "olly olly in come free"

```
olly: 2
in: 1
come: 1
free: 1
```

I'm at a point where I'm pretty sure I have the answer figured out in theory, but I'm having trouble with types. After splitting the string, I run a reduce function that returns a `Map<string, number>`, like this:

```
    return string.split(' ').reduce((acc: Map<string, number>, word): Map<string, number> => {
      if (acc.has(word)) {
        console.log("working")
        // I've tried this
        return acc[word] + 1
        // And this
        return acc.set(word, acc.get(word) + 1)
      } else {
        return acc.set(word, 1)
      }
    }, new Map<string, number>())
```

A couple of problems I've run into as I've been tweaking this are

1) `acc` has no "has" method (when I type `acc` as `any` instead of Map)

2) `acc.get(word)` could be undefined, and so doesn't work (which I check for, but Typescript doesn't see?)

Of course, I'm open to the possibility of just doing this wrong anyway, but is there any way to make what I have work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Map` in JavaScript and therefore TypeScript does not store its key/value pairs as properties directly on the object, so the `acc[word]` notation will not work unless you replace your `Map` with a dictionary object type like `{[k: string]: number | undefined}`.  That's not a bad way to go, but presumably you want to use a `Map` instead of a plain object for some reason, so we'll stick with that.

---

TypeScript doesn't understand that a `Map` instance's `has(x)` method returning `true` means that a subsequent call to `get(x)` will not be `undefined`.  There's no good way even to represent such a constraint.  You could augment the [existing typings for `Map`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) to make the `has(x)` method act as a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for either the `Map` instance or maybe for the `x` parameter, which could *sort of* work, depending on what you're doing, but it's a lot of complexity and would be very brittle.

If I wanted to keep your `return acc.set(word, acc.get(word) + 1)` line as-is in JavaScript, I'd say to use the [non-null assertion operator `!`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) on the result of `acc.get(word)`.  Here, you know that checking `acc.has(word)` implies that `acc.get(word)` will be a `number` and not `number | undefined`, but the compiler doesn't know this.  And whenever you are sure of something that the compiler doesn't know, it's reasonable to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  Here's how it would look:

```
if (acc.has(word)) {
  return acc.set(word, acc.get(word)! + 1); // no error now
}
```

So, that's great.  All done!

---

Still, type assertions can just hide potential errors... it's usually preferable to use code that the compiler can actually *verify* as type safe rather than code that we have to *assert* is safe.  So what can we do to get the compiler to help *us* instead of the other way around?

Well, we're using `acc.has(word)` as a way to narrow the result of `acc.get(word)`.  But what if we just save the result of `acc.get(word)` and check it directly?  Then we could forget about the `has()` method entirely.  Something like:

```
const cnt = acc.get(word);
if (typeof cnt !== 'undefined') {
  return acc.set(word, cnt + 1); // no error here
} else {
  return acc.set(word, 1);
}
```

We've explicitly checked `cnt` for being `undefined`, and the normal [control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis) understands that `cnt` is a `number` inside of the `true` clause of the `if` statement.

Okay, now we're all done!

---

Hmm, but `typeof cnt === "undefined"` is wordy; we could just check if `cnt` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), which it is for all `number` values except `0`.  And since we're treating the `undefined` case as if the count were `0` anyway, it doesn't hurt to do that:

```
const cnt = acc.get(word);
if (cnt) {
  return acc.set(word, cnt + 1);
} else {
  return acc.set(word, 1);
}
```

And wait, once we are willing to check truthiness, we could use the [logical "or" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) to just make sure that `cnt` is *always* a `number`:

```
const cnt = acc.get(word) || 0; // always a number
if (cnt) {
  return acc.set(word, cnt + 1);
} else {
  return acc.set(word, 1);
}
```

But now we know that the only falsy value of `cnt` is `0`, so we can *always* do `cnt + 1`:

```
const cnt = acc.get(word) || 0;
return acc.set(word, cnt + 1);
```

And now `cnt` is used precisely once, so it's not worth having it be a separate variable:

```
return acc.set(word, (acc.get(word) || 0) + 1);
```

Oh and an arrow function with just a single `return` statement in it can be changed to one that uses a [concise body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body):

```
function countStuff(string: string) {
  return string
    .split(" ")
    .reduce(
      (acc: Map<string, number>, word): Map<string, number> =>
        acc.set(word, (acc.get(word) || 0) + 1),
      new Map<string, number>()
    );
}
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBO4oGUomMAFAZygCcYwBzALkUJPIEpEBvAKEUSIFMsikbSzWbRADp8ABwA2MKLgBEiWXUFthnACYgIHXMqG4AhhAhUAsvrEAePuQA0iMCAC2AIw5EAfHYDucImrqm5lbE-HYOLm7uiAC87rpCiIYQoly4Pn52BkbCZKnp-ogAPoWIAAwMANSIAIx0NvH2HF6IZpbWZGFOrh64Sgl0ANzMAL7MQA)

Okay, now we're all done!  Or at least *I* am.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me like that, it was really helpful!